# IOptionsSnapshot in .net core Console application not working

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

Below is the example of .NET Core console application, uses constructor dependency injection with `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", 
                optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        IServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .Configure<AppSettings>(
                configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"))
            .AddTransient<CheckOption>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.ReadLine() != "stop")
            {
                CheckOption checkOption = 
                    provider.GetRequiredService<CheckOption>();

                checkOption.Run();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CheckOption
{
    public AppSettings _AppSettings;     

    public CheckOption(IOptionsSnapshot<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _AppSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    public void Run()
    {            
      string option1 = _AppSettings.Option1;
      string option2 = _AppSettings.Option2;
    }
}

public class AppSettings
{
    public string Option1 {get; set;}
    public string Option2 {get; set;}
}
```

Values of `Option1` and `Option2` remains same, on change of "appsettings.json" in while loop.

Comment: Change the line `.BuildServiceProvider()` to `.BuildServiceProvider(true)` and you'll see where the problem lies.

Comment: "InvalidOperationException". Cannot resolve CheckOption from root provider because it requires scoped service IOptionsSnapshot at "GetRequiredService<CheckOption>()".

Comment: Exactly. There lies the problem. Now go learn about scopes and scoped services in the MS.DI container. Its documentation does a pretty good job in explaining this.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.